# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
for file in zip(frames_list[-round(0.2 * len(frames_list)):], masks_list[-round(0.2 * len(masks_list)):]):
    # Convert tensors to numpy arrays
    frame = frame_batches.next().numpy().astype(np.uint8)
    mask = mask_batches.next().numpy().astype(np.uint8)

    # Convert numpy arrays to images
    frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
    mask = Image.fromarray(mask)

    # Save frames and masks to correct directories
    frame.save(DATA_PATH + '{}_frames/{}'.format(dir_name, dir_name) + '/' + file[0])
    mask.save(DATA_PATH + '{}_masks/{}'.format(dir_name, dir_name) + '/' + file[1])

print("Saved {} frames to directory {}".format(len(frames_list), DATA_PATH))
print("Saved {} masks to directory {}".format(len(masks_list), DATA_PATH))
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/Khawar_Seg/main.py", line 190, in <module>
    generate_image_folder_structure(frame_tensors, masks_tensors, frames_list, masks_list)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/Khawar_Seg/main.py", line 173, in generate_image_folder_structure
    for file in zip(frames_list[-round(0.2 * len(frames_list)):], masks_list[-round(0.2 * len(masks_list)):]):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what is ```frames_list``` and ```len(frames_list)```?

Comment: ['0016E5_07983.png', '0016E5_08077.png', '0016E5_08067.png', '0016E5_08081.png', '0016E5_07993.png' and len of framelist is 101

Comment: You've changed your post to include even less detail.  it's important to keep ```frames_list[:-round(0.2 * len(frames_list))]``` as is provides context.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, i have resolved one error. Now error is just validation part

Comment: That's much better!  Thanks!

Comment: Now you understand better. i updated complete code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221295/discussion-between-khawar-islam-and-ewong).

Comment: `round` returns a float on Python 2.

Comment: lets suppose, I need integer then?

Comment: Compiler error : TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica brilliant catch!!!

Comment: I am keep trying to solve what is the meaning of ":" in for file in zip(frames_list[-round(0.2 * len(frames_list)):]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `round` function in python 2.7 returns a `float` type, but the sequence slice is expecting an `int` as the argument.

```py
>>> type(round(2.0))
<type 'float'>

>>> items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> items[round(2.0):]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

# If we cast the rounded index to an int, it will work
>>> index = int(round(2.0))
>>> type(index)
<type 'int'>

>>> items[int(round(2.0)):]
[2, 3, 4]
```

So, for your example code, you need to cast the indices to integers before using them in the slice -- the `[<start>:<end>]` part of your for loop.

```py
frames_index = -int(round(0.2 * len(frames_list)))
masks_index = -int(round(0.2 * len(masks_list)))

for file in zip(frames_list[frames_index:], masks_list[masks_index:]):
    ...
```

To make things easier to read, I suggest that you use a function to make your index numbers:

```py
def get_list_index(list_size):  # list_size is the len(<list>)
    float_value = round(0.2 * list_size)
    return -int(float_value)

frames_index = get_list_index(len(frames_list))
masks_index = get_list_index(len(masks_list))

for file in zip(frames_list[frames_index:], masks_list[masks_index:]):
    ...
```

**Edit:**

To answer the question in your comment:

> what is the meaning of `:` in for file in `zip(frames_list[-round(0.2 * len(frames_list)):]`?

The `:` separates the *start* index from the *end* index in python slice notation.

For instance, if you have the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and you wanted to get only the portion from `'b'` through `'d'`, you would use a slice starting from `1` and ending on `4` -- _1 more than `'d'`'s index.

```py
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][1:4]
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Python lets you use *negative* indexing, so you can count back from the right side. We could write the same slice using `-1` instead of `3`:

```py
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][1:-1]
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

If we wanted to have *all* of the items in the list, starting at `'b'` and going through the end, we can change our right index to `None` or just leave it out:

```py
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][1:None]
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][1:]
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Please tell me one thing. Is it right now?     for file in zip(frames_list[-int(round(0.2 * len(frames_list)))], masks_list[-int(round(0.2 * len(masks_list)))]):
?